# Codeigniter4 Email showing Html Source

Tags: php, codeigniter, shared-hosting, codeigniter-4

I am having trouble with displaying email in codeigniter4

I have just deployed the application to shared hosting

However emails are not displayed correctly, it just showing html source instead.

See below

```html
<p>to reset your password.<br/>
<br />
If you did not request a password reset, you can safely ignore this
email.<br />
<br />
Yours,<br />
</p>
```

```
    $email = \Config\Services::email();

    $email->setFrom($settings->info->site_noreply_email, $settings->info->site_title);
    $email->setTo($emailTo);
    $email->setSubject($subject, $settings->info->site_title);
    $email->setMessage($body);
    $email->send();
```

If anyone ever came across this please help

Comment: Just a note: `$email->setSubject(...);` [expects one parameter, not two](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/3800c5d4f22bc30a44577418d9814f33f4a030d5/system/Email/Email.php#L615) as shown in your question description.

Answer (score 0):

Check your mail Type in config.

**In `app/config/Email.php`**

```
public $mailType = 'html';
```

or before send initialize it

```
$config['mailType'] = 'html;
$email->initialize($config);
```

Answer (score 0):

*Before* `$email->send();`, call:

```php
    $email->setMailType("html");
```

Reference: [\CodeIgniter\Email\Email::setMailType($type = 'text')](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/3800c5d4f22bc30a44577418d9814f33f4a030d5/system/Email/Email.php#L751)

Comment: After adding i am now getting the following `This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ALT_62dd9263c816f4.72645602
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit eset your password.=3Cbr /=3E
=3Cbr /=3E
If you did not request a password reset, you can safely ignore this email.=
=3Cbr /=3E
=3Cbr /=3E
Yours,=3Cbr /=3E
Your friends at City Striders Club=3C/p=3E

--B_ALT_62dd9263c816f4.72645602--`

Comment: @Kandonga *Before* `$email->send();` and *after* `$email->setMailType("html");`, add `$email->sendMultipart = false;`

Comment: Where do i add this line `$email->sendMultipart = false;` is it before send() or after send because when i add it get error `Call to undefined method $email->sendMultipart`

Comment: After that i am now getting this `=3Cbr /=3E
If you did not request a password reset, you can safely ignore this email.=
=3Cbr /=3E
=3Cbr /=3E
Yours,=3Cbr /=3E`